# onselectindexchange event is not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the below code I have a dropdown when I select a value the `onselectedindexchanged` is not firing the event.I have tried but I cant get the expected result. So can anyone help me ?

**code**:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cbAutoList"
                  runat="server"
                  CssClass="cbAutoList1"
                  AutoPostBack="true"
                  OnSelectedIndexChanged="cbAutoList_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Value="hai"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="hello"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**Codebehind**

```
public delegate void LeavingFocusHandler(int CurrentIndex);

public event LeavingFocusHandler LeavingFocus;
public string strValue { get; set; } 
public int ItemIndex { get; set; }

protected void cbAutoList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (cbAutoList.Items.Count > 0)
            this.strValue = cbAutoList.Items[cbAutoList.SelectedIndex].ToString();
        else
            this.strValue = string.Empty;

        if (this.LeavingFocus != null)
        {
            this.LeavingFocus(this.ItemIndex);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the aspx you have just one ListItem? How SelectedIndexChanged would fire if there is just one element?

Comment: i have checked with more than one element it is not firing

Comment: You have only 1 item in the dropdownlist. Add more listitems to dropdown list.

Comment: i add multiple values it throws error Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList.

Comment: i have checked ur code on my side. its working fine. Where did you get this error?? in pageload??

Comment: Do you use something like UpdatePanel?

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested your code its working fie at my side. Please make a test project and try this in `Default.aspx` its working fine.

```
protected void cbAutoList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (cbAutoList.Items.Count > 0)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

<asp:DropDownList ID="cbAutoList" runat="server" CssClass="cbAutoList1" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cbAutoList_SelectedIndexChanged">
   <asp:ListItem Value="hai"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="hello"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: i am binding the dropdown list to datalist will that be a issue

Comment: @user3224577 at very first it must fire the event. Did you try this ?

Comment: @ Afnan Ahmad it did not fire the event.

Comment: @user3224577 would you please try this in test project ? I am sure you are missing some thins. I just have checked this in test project and it is working fine.